# How is the inheritance working here?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I dont know for sure how the code works. How *A* c0 = new C();* even work? How can I make a pointer 'A' object from a 'C'?

```
class A {
public:
    A() { print("Constructor of A"); }
    virtual ~A() { print("Destructor of A"); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { print("Constructor of B"); }
    ~B() { print("Destructor of B"); }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C() { print("Constructor of C"); }
    ~C() { print("Destructor of C"); }
};

int main() {
    print("A* = C");
    A* c0 = new C();
    delete c0;

    print("B* = C");
    B* c1 = new C();
    delete c1;

    print("C* = C");
    C* c2 = new C();
    delete c2;

    return 0;
}
```

I thought I understood the inheritance a long time ago but now when I needed to use it I just got lost in the code.

Comment: `class C : public B` means "a `C` is a `B`". Furthermore a `B` is an `A`, so a `C` is also an `A`. Since a `C` is an `A` it is not surprising that you can assign it to an `A*`.

Comment: Um... But this code uses only very basic, "kindergarten grade" inheritance-related features of the language. How is it possible to "understand the inheritance", yet "get lost" in this?

Answer (score 1):

Since `C` inherits from `B`, which inherits from `A`, `C` indirectly inherits from `A`. As such, every instance of `C` is also an instance of `A`. Therefore, a value of type `C*` can be directly converted to a value of type `A*`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Inheritance !!
Continuous inheritence hierarchy speaks the truth..

```
*************************************
A Base
B Base + (Something )
C Base + (Something ) + (Something ) 
**************************************
```

Remember like the above picture.. so now you can see that C contains the Base which is absolutely A itself.. so the thing works for you ..

Answer (score 0):

Since a C is derived from A, then all C objects are (isA) A's.  The new operator creates a C, and since a C "isA" A it can be assigned to an A* pointer.

When using an A* pointer, you can only call functions which are defined in class A. (because the pointer type is an A)

When you have a C* pointer to a C object, you can call any of the functions in A,B, or C. (Assuming they are public or protected).

If you have a virtual function "f", and a non-virtual function "g" defined in each of the classes, and the following assignments:

A* pA = new A;
A* pAC = new C;
C* pC = new C;

then,

pA->f() will call A::f();
pA->g() will call A::g();

pAC->f() will call A::f();
pAC->g() will call C::g();

pC->f() will call C::f();
pC->g() will call C::g();

Note that the real area of interest is in the pAC example. Calling the virtual function always calls the implementation of the actual object. Calling the plain function call the implementation based on the pointer type.